# Segfault 11 on long string, PRIOR to accessing string, only when string > 14

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ansi-c

ANSI c on OSX 10.13.6 
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix

I'm learning `c`

This is a function that manually (character-by-character) adds two **character strings** representing large numbers (that exceed the unsigned long long or double size).

It functions fine with any two strings **14 or less characters long**, but `segmentation fault 11` with any strings **greater than 14 chars**.

**Changing the string's memory allocation method seems to have no effect** (I.e. from
 `char[15] addend1; // not a ptr` 
to 
 `char *addend1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (16) ); // pointer`

**One things that's curious**, is that it seems to segfault on the ...

`for (int j = maxlength - 1 ; j >= 0; j--)`
... prior to accessing either of `addend1` or `addend2`, but I'm not able to find an error there or change it to prevent the segfault.

**Am I misreading where the error arises, or could it be related to the for loop?**

***Successful run (less than 15 chars)***

```
maxlength = 14
char *sum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) ) ... DONE
for (int i = 0; i < (maxlength); i++) { sum[i] = '0'; } ... DONE
Start adding individual ints from end (right side) ...
13 ...12 ...11 ...10 ...9 ...8 ...7 ...6 ...5 ...4 ...3 ...2 ...1 ...0 ...main.sum = 28147497671064
```

***UNSuccessful run (15 chars)***

```
maxlength = 15
char *sum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) ) ... DONE
for (int i = 0; i < (maxlength); i++) { sum[i] = '0'; } ... DONE
Start adding individual ints from end (right side) ...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

***MAIN.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../../c-library/include/addViaStrings.h"

int main(void) {
    //  s[0] = 72; s[1] = 101; s[2] = 108; s[3] = 108; s[4] = 111; s[5] = 32; s[6] = 87; s[7] = 111; s[8] = 114; s[9] = 108; s[10] = 100; s[11] = 0;

    // WORKS
    // char s1[] = "14073748835532";
    // char s2[] = "14073748835532";

    // FAILS
    char s1[] = "140737488355328";
    char s2[] = "140737488355328";

    char *sum = addNumericStrings(&s1, &s2);
    printf("main.sum = %s\n", sum);
}
```

***addViaStrings.h***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char* addNumericStrings(char *s1, char *s2);
char leftPad(char *result, char *s, int maxlength);
int  findMaxLength(char *s1, char *s2);

char* addNumericStrings(char *s1, char *s2){
    // Find the length of the greater of the two
    int maxlength = findMaxLength(s1, s2);
    printf("maxlength = %d\n", maxlength); //333

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Using malloc instead of char[maxlength] seems to have NO EFFECT on the issue
    // char addend1[maxlength]; // not a pointer
    char *addend1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) );
    addend1[maxlength + 1] = 0; // end flag

    // char addend2[maxlength]; // not a pointer
    char *addend2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) );
    addend2[maxlength + 1] = 0; // end flag

    // Allocate sum pointer
    printf("char *sum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) ) ... "); //333
    char *sum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) );
    printf("DONE\n"); //333

    // General use vars
    int a1, a2, total;
    int carry = 0;

    // Prepare the strings for manual addition. Pad the left with char 0s
    leftPad(addend1, s1, maxlength);
    leftPad(addend2, s2, maxlength);

    // Buffer sum with zeros
    sum[maxlength + 1] = 0; // end flag
    printf("for (int i = 0; i < (maxlength); i++) { sum[i] = '0'; } ... "); //333
    for (int i = 0; i < (maxlength); i++) { sum[i] = '0'; } // Fill w/ 0s
    printf("DONE\n"); //333

    // Run the manual addition
    // Start adding individual ints from end (right side)
    printf("Start adding individual ints from end (right side) ...\n"); //333

    // maxlength -1 because(I think) the termination char takes 2 bytes
    // If I use (maxlength) instead of (maxlength -1) I get a weird 
    //  question mark char at the end of returnsum
    for (int j = maxlength - 1 ; j >= 0; j--) {

        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        // The segfault seems to happen BEFORE accessing addend1 or addend2
        printf("%d ...", j); // 333 This DOES NOT print
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        a1 = addend1[j] - '0'; // Convert to int
        a2 = addend2[j] - '0'; // Convert to int
        total = (a1 + a2 + carry);
        carry = 0;
        if ( total >= 10){
            carry += 1;
            total -= 10;
        }
        sum[j + 1] = '0'+total; // convert to ascii value for numbers (adding 48)
    }
    sum[0] = '0' + carry; // add last carry to start of num always, even if 0
    // Before returning, truncate leading zeros
    char *returnsum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(sum) + 1) );
    int sum_i = 0;
    int returnsm_i = 0;
//    bool truncate = true; // Find out why this wont compile
    int truncate = 1; // true
    while (1){
        // if order is important here
        if (sum[sum_i] == '\0') { break; } // we're done
        if (sum[sum_i] == '0' && truncate == 1) { sum_i += 1; continue; } // 1 is true
        // if a num, Stop truncating 0s but DO continue adding numbers
        if (sum[sum_i] != '0') { truncate = 0; } // 0 is false
        returnsum[returnsm_i] = sum[sum_i];
        returnsm_i += 1;
        sum_i += 1;
    }
    return returnsum;
}

char leftPad(char *result, char *s, int maxlength){
    int slength = strlen(s);
    // buffer with zeros, not '\0's
    for (int i = (maxlength); i >= 0; i--){ result[i] = '0'; }
    // right fill result with s
    for (int j = 0; j <= slength; j++){
        int index = ((maxlength - slength) + j);
        result[index] = s[j];
    }
    result[maxlength + 1] = 0;

}

int findMaxLength(char *s1, char *s2){
//  int length1 = findEndLength(s1);
//  int length2 = findEndLength(s2);
    int length1 = strlen(s1);
    int length2 = strlen(s2);
    int maxlength;
    (length1 > length2) ? (maxlength = length1) : (maxlength = length2);
    return maxlength;
}
```

Comment: What does `findMaxLength` do? Or `leftPad`? A [mcve] would be very useful here

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks for the comment. I've added them to the OP.

Comment: `sum[maxlength + 1] = 0;` is wrong: although you alocate `maxlength + 1` characters, the last valid index is just `maxlength`. (Indices in C go from `0..n-1`, remember?)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks for the comment. I chose `maxlength + 1` because the actual number of digits in the string are 15 (maxlength) and then I use the 16th index for the termination char. However, if I change it to `sum[maxlength] = 0;`, I get the same `segfault 11` - but now it starts erroring out at adding two 14 char long strings instead of two 15 char long strings. Adding two strings between 1 and 13 chars still works however.

Comment: Guess you should use a debugger to step through the program and see what happens. I never see you terminate the strings with `'\0'`. Does your `leftPad` work?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Good point. I updated the OP to add `addend1[maxlength + 1] = 0; // end flag` for addend1 and 2. Originally, I had used a `char addend1[]` so I hadn't needed to manually add a terminator (**Is that correct?**) Unfortunately, the change doesn't seem to have affected the results. The `leftpad` does seem to work, but I'll double-check it.

Comment: Again: indices in C go from `0..n-1`. So if you allocate `maxlength+1` characters, then _the last index is_ `(maxlenght+1)-1`, i.e. `maxlength`. `addend1[maxlength+1`] __does not exist__.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Good point. Although, since I'm declaring using `malloc (maxlength + 1)`  (**NOT** `char[maxlength]`) then doesn't that mean that I have "maxlength" for actual characters and use index (maxlength + 1) for the terminator? BTW Should we move this to chat?

Comment: You are correct that if you declare a `char` array without explicit length and provide a string literal initializer, then you will automatically get the initializer's terminator in your array, along with the rest of its contents.

Comment: @RightmireM, the range of valid indexes does not depend on whether the array is allocated statically, automatically, or dynamically.  If the length of the array is `arraylength` elements, then the valid indexes are `0`, `1`, ... `arraylength - 1`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie P.S. I added an explicit terminator to `leftPad()` in the form of `result[maxlength + 1] = 0;` ... but it doesn't change the behavior of the program (or the segfault) at all.

Comment: Therefore, whether you use `char[maxlength + 1]` or `malloc(maxlength + 1)`, the largest index you may use is `maxlength` (***not*** `maxlength + 1`).

Comment: Dear Mr. Rightmire. We seem not able to get it into your head that the _size_ of an array is one more than the index of its last element and that a string requires _one more_ character for its terminating null character. So `"hello"` has 6 characters, `'h' 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'`. `'h'` occupies position `0` and the `'\0'` occupies position `5`.

Comment: ... and that, therefore, the index of the terminator of `"hello"` is ***5***, not ***6***.  That is, the index of a string's terminator is the same as that string's length.  All of this follows from counting from 0 instead of from 1.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Hi Paul. No. I totally understand that :) It's the same in Python (my background). "H" in your example is `var[0]`, "e" is `var[1]`, etc. Nonetheless, the solution was, in fact, in the malloc of `sum`. It needed to be `maxlength + 2` ... so I guess, that was exactly your point. If you want to make that as an answer instead of comment, then I'll accept it for credit. Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, yes actually all the `maxlength + 1`s needed to be just `maxlength` and the `sum` variable needed to be `maxlength + 1` (one digit longer than the addends in case they carried a final 1). It was the failure of sum's allocation that caused the segfault. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I am afraid you fixed a symptom, but not the cause.

Comment: First step: remove all dynamic allocation and use fixed sized buffers. Get the addition working. Next step: change to dynamic allocation. one by one.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie No. I believe the cause has also been resolved. The `addend`s have all had memory declared at `maxsize`, the sum (needing to be one character larger than the addends) have been declared at `maxsize + 1`. The addends' terminators (`\0`) are at `addends[maxsize - 1]`and the sum's terminator is at `sum[maxsize]`. What is still incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was trying to access the `sum` string as if it was one position longer than the `addends` strings, but I had declared it as the same length (I.e. `maxlength + 1`). So I was attempting to access one position past the actual `sum` array.

*This was a somewhat hidden problem, because it was not until the length of `sum` needed to be greater than 15, that this access error stepped into disallowed memory space, resulting in a segfault.*

**Details**

Because the sum of two addends could conceivably require at least one additional position in the array if the sums carried over a one (I.e. 999 + 999 = 1998), the `sum` string needs to be one array position longer than the addends.

If the addends were 3 digits long (length of array = 4) then the sum needed to be 4 digits long (array length = 5).

```
// Correct code if "maxlength" (number of actual digits in string) = 14
char *addend1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) ); // +1 To include termination byte
char *addend2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 1) ); // +1 To include termination byte
char *sum     = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (maxlength + 2) ); // +2 To include termination byte, AND an extra char at the front
```

...so that the final actual digit character of `sum` is accessed via `maxlength + 1`

***CORRECTED CODE***

*NOTE: Because calculating against `maxlength` as the number of digits (versus the length of the entire array including terminator) was confusing - as well as considered bad form, I have since learned - the following final code has been simplified to use more intuitive variables.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* addIntsAsStrings(char *s1, char *s2);

char* addIntsAsStrings(char *s1, char *s2){
    // Find the length of the greater of the two
    int length1 = strlen(s1);
    int length2 = strlen(s2);
    int addendDigits;
    (length1 > length2) ? (addendDigits = length1) : (addendDigits = length2);

    // We need separate strings of so they can be buffered with zeros
    // Create the string for the addends and buffer with zeros.
    char addend1[addendDigits + 1];
    char addend2[addendDigits + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < (addendDigits) ; i++){ // "<" not "<="
        addend1[i] = '0'; // buffer w/ 0s
        addend2[i] = '0'; // buffer w/ 0s
    } // buffer w/ 0s
    addend1[addendDigits] = '\0'; // terminate

    // put s1 and s2 into buffered addends strings
    int s1_index = (strlen(s1) - 1);
    int s2_index = (strlen(s2) - 1);
    for (int i = (addendDigits - 1); i >= 0; i--){ //Start at back of addend
        if ( s1_index >= 0) { addend1[i] = s1[s1_index]; }
        if ( s2_index >= 0) { addend2[i] = s2[s2_index]; }
        s1_index -= 1;
        s2_index -= 1;
    }

    // Allocate sum pointer. The sum pointer needs to be ONE char
    //  longer than the addends, in the event that the addends need
    //  to carry a final one to the front. I.e. 999 + 999 = 1998
    int sumDigits = addendDigits + 1;
    char *sum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (sumDigits + 1) ); // +1 To include termination byte, AND an extra char at the front
    for (int i = 0; i < (sumDigits) ; i++){ // "<" not "<="
        sum[i] = '0'; // buffer w/ 0s
    }
    sum[sumDigits] = '\0';

    // Manual addition vars
    int a1, a2, total;
    int carry = 0;

    // Run the manual addition
    // Start adding individual ints from end (right side)
    for (int j = addendDigits - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        a1 = addend1[j] - '0'; // Convert to int
        a2 = addend2[j] - '0'; // Convert to int
        total = (a1 + a2 + carry);
        carry = 0;
        if ( total >= 10){
            carry += 1;
            total -= 10;
        }
        // convert to ascii value for numbers (adding 48)
        sum[j + 1] = '0'+total; // sum[j + 1] because `sum`is always one index larger than the addends
    }
    sum[0] = '0' + carry; // add last carry to start of num always, even if 0

    // Before returning, truncate leading zeros
    char *returnsum = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(sum) + 1) );
    int sum_i = 0;
    int returnsm_i = 0;
    int truncate = 1; // true
    while (1){
        // if order is important here
        if (sum[sum_i] == '\0') { break; } // we're done
        if (sum[sum_i] == '0' && truncate == 1) { sum_i += 1; continue; } // 1 is true
        // if a num, Stop truncating 0s but DO continue adding numbers
        if (sum[sum_i] != '0') { truncate = 0; } // 0 is false
        returnsum[returnsm_i] = sum[sum_i];
        returnsm_i += 1;
        sum_i += 1;
    }
    return returnsum;
}
```

[image: Array Lengths]